# Overwrite mvc_helper.php in WPMVC to modify the default table view in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a helper to change the default view of index page in wordpress.

My plugin is WPMVC generated and as per instructions in the official tutorial of WPMVC, i have created and loaded the helper but it is not working.

Can any one show me the right way to proceed?

Check the below link for a screen shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a1Ao.png

In the screeshot, the links and button below the records are added by me, overwriting the index file.

Now, i need to add a link near 'Edit | View | Delete' in the image, like,

Edit | View | Add Rule | Delete

Any suggestions on how to do that?

As i have told earlier, i created and loaded the helper but it is not functioning.

Need help. Thanks.

Codes:

/app/helpers/geozone_helper.php (Create Helper):

```
<?php 
class GeozoneHelper extends MvcHelper {

public $_redirect_action = '';

public function __construct() {
    if(empty($this->_redirect_action)) {
        $this->_redirect_action = 'geozone_rules-add';
    }       
    parent::__construct();
}

public function admin_actions_cell($controller, $object) {
    $links = array();
    $object_name = empty($object->__name) ? 'Item #'.$object->__id : $object->__name;
    $encoded_object_name = $this->esc_attr($object_name);
    $links[] = '<a href="'.MvcRouter::admin_url(array('object' => $object, 'action' => 'edit')).'" title="Edit '.$encoded_object_name.'">Edit</a>';
    $links[] = '<a href="'.MvcRouter::public_url(array('object' => $object)).'" title="View '.$encoded_object_name.'">View</a>';
    $links[] = '<a href="'.MvcRouter::admin_url(array('object' => $object, 'action' => $this->_redirect_action)).'" title="Edit '.$encoded_object_name.'">Add Rule</a>';
    $links[] = '<a href="'.MvcRouter::admin_url(array('object' => $object, 'action' => 'delete')).'" title="Delete '.$encoded_object_name.'" onclick="return confirm(&#039;Are you sure you want to delete '.$encoded_object_name.'?&#039;);">Delete</a>';
    $html = implode(' | ', $links);
    return '<td>'.$html.'</td>';
 }
}
```

/app/controllers/geozones_controller.php (load helper):

```
public function show() {

    $object = $this->model->find_by_id($this->params['id'], array(
        'includes' => array('Geozone')));

    if (!empty($object)) {
        $this->set('object', $object);
        $this->render_view('show', array('layout' => 'public'));
    }
    $this->load_helper('geozone');
    $this->set_object();
}
```

/app/view/geozones/show.php (link to the helper):

```
 <h2><?php echo $object->__name; ?></h2>

 <p>
    <?php echo $this->html->link('&#8592; All Geozones', array('controller' =>   'geozones')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->geozone->admin_actions_cell($controller, $object->content); ?>
 </p>
```

Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved like this: The function

```
public function show() {
  $this->load_helper('geozone');
  $this->set_object();
}
```

in public controller is shifted to admin controller and function name is changed to index() like this:

```
public function index() {
  $this->load_helper('geozone');
  $this->set_objects();
}
```

Thanks for everyone who tried to solve this.